# permission IAM accidentally removed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-iam

I removed my permission from my project in google app engine, now I can not access more functionality of my project, which is still online, but I can not access any more, everything I click returns that I am not allowed

Comment: What you were ? Owner? And do you mean now you're not able to go back and give yourselves the removed permission back? What & you have already tried ? Have you checked : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/granting-project-access..
please provide more details !

Comment: That. I am the sole owner of the project. In the IAM page, it has all the permissions, I created some, and it was remove, but I removed the main one, that was of the project DONOR, in this way, I lost all the permissions of everything, and I can no longer access to remove the project , or modify it. :( I've tried what shows by the link, without success. The project is not even listed for me to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just tried changing Roles in my GAE project, since I am the only sole owner.

**GAE doesn't allowed that to happen.**

Please re-check, there must be another owner which you're not aware or you have given some-one Owner role and that is the reason it happened.

[image]
*PS :Posting in answer to attach image.*

Comment: Has no way. On the IAM screen, you have the listing of the members, one of them is the owner, who is your EU. By chance I removed this MEMBER, I immediately got without permission for this project, so much that it is not even listed for me, but the instances are running, and I have no access to remove.

Comment: @Pimenta , this seems very accidental.As for me it seems, an impossible scenario. Thus, doubt that there is a direct solution. Better you raise a support ticket. https://cloud.google.com/support/
I am sure you would have gone through this also :https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access
and
lastly : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine